# Programs with available code for practice

Tags: c#

I'm currently learning C# and was wondering if there are any sites that provide like an assigment to build working basic program, but has the full code available, so you could use it if you're completely lost.

I did maybe 20 ProjectEuler questions, but they're mostly math questions and I really need some practice in building actual programs, because now after reading few C# books i still have very limited understanding how to make the whole interconnected systems.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Infer-On hey, thanks for the link, haven't seen that one yet. But those are pretty much the same problems as in the books, they do not build actual programs that do something, but just work on theoretical problems to show how to use the specific methods

Comment: ok, you need something like http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of question is a good case for 2 things that are useful. One: an imagination. Think very carefully of normal tasks you do every day that could be accomplished or simplified by writing a program. If none exist (which is likely) then this is where the second option comes in to play. It requires a little explanation though. One practice that is starting to become more popular (but also has a lot of discussion about how to do it properly) is Test Driven Development (TDD). Now I'm not going to tell you how to do TDD, nor am I going to say go down that path. One of the excercises though to get used to TDD is what is helpful though. They call it a Kata. In America we would call it a drill, or excercise. Something we repeate frequently to drive home the point. (Anyone remember multiplication table drills?)

Anywho. What is nice about this is that the test framework (NUnit) is a very easy to understand system of pass or fail. You'll know if you got the code right. Since the majority of all programs is the logic and implementation, and in comparison little is on the view of the program it isn't a bad place to start. To help with this if you look into NuGet you can download two very small packages. Nunit, and Nunit test runner. With those two packages you can run a Nunit test inside Visual Studio easily and with hardly any setup. One of my favorite Kata's to do is the Bowling Score Keeper. In my opinion writing tests to learn a language is a very effective tool in learning it. You'll learn by doing, and you'll have the same language telling you if you did it right or not.